# Globally installed NPM packages not recognised

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, global

I had a system crash. While trying to fix it, I deleted a few files and (I may be wrong here), I deleted `~/.profile` file among them.

After system restore, my globally installed npm packages are not working.

I uninstalled npm and node and installed the latest version of nodejs 16.x, and then reinstalled globally required npm packages, however, they are still not working. Somewhere the environment variables (in .profile file?) have gone missing.

How can I get the globally installed packages to run?

Comment: From the command line, or from a node environment?

Comment: from commandline

Comment: Check out [option 2](http://npm.github.io/installation-setup-docs/installing/a-note-on-permissions.html) on how to set up your `~/.profile` file. You just need to add the npm-global/bin to your PATH.

Comment: That did it, thank you so much. It would be great to have that as an answer so if I make that mistake again, I will find it :) Cheers Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the path to the globally installed npm modules in your `PATH`. There are multiple fixes described on [this page](http://npm.github.io/installation-setup-docs/installing/a-note-on-permissions.html), one of which:

> Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line: 
> `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`  
> Back on the command line, update your system variables:
> `source ~/.profile`